# Odd promiseKit 6 syntax behavior in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I am getting started with PromiseKit to prevent myself from writing functions with 10 levels of callbacks..

I installed the latest version (6.2.4) using CocoaPods, am running the latest version of xCode, imported PromiseKit in the file I am trying to get it working in, but I get really weird behavior of Xcode, resulting in several errors.

I intend to do something really basic to get started:

the function below creates filters (`ProductListComponents`) for categories for products in a product overview app I'm working on.

```
func createCategoryComponents(masterComponent: MasterComponent?) -> Promise<[ProductListComponents]> {
    return Promise { seal in
        //create a bunch of product category components
        seal.resolve([components])
    }
}
```

All fine here. I then try to get this:

```
firstly {
    self.createCategoryComponents(masterComponent: masterComponent)
}.then { createdComponents in
    completion.resolve(nil, createdComponents)
}
```

This refuses to work. firstly, when I try to type the `firstly` code, Xcode suggests:

```
firstly(execute: { () -> Guarantee<T> in
    //code
})
```

and:

```
firstly(execute: { () -> Thenable in
    //code
})
```

I have not seen this syntax in ANY of the PromiseKit documentation. It also suggests odd syntax for e.g. the .then calls. When accepting Xcode's suggestions, it obviously displays error as this is not the correct PromiseKit syntax. When ignoring Xcode's suggestion, I get this:

[image]

Obviously something is wrong here, my best guess is that something went wrong with the installation of PromiseKit. I have cleaned my project, re-installed the pod, restarted Xcode but it seems that nothing is working.

**Question**

Does anybody know what kind of issue I'm experiencing here and, even more importantly, how I might get it resolved?

Any helpt would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to return the `Promise` in `firstly` like this: `firstly{return self.createCategoryComponents(masterComponent: masterComponent)}.then{...`.

Comment: Hi @DávidPásztor, Thank hou for your comment. I have tried your approach but it does not seem to solve the problem. Would you have any other ideas how I can get the PromiseKit syntax to work like in their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://promisekit.org/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/):

> - `then` is fed the previous promise value and requires you return a promise.
> - `done` is fed the previous promise value and returns a Void promise (which is 80% of chain usage)
> - `map` is fed the previous promise value and requires you return a non-promise, ie. a value.

So, `then` shouldn't work here, because you need to return the promise value. If you just change `then` to the `done` it will work.

Also some suggestions.

- `firstly` is really about visual decoration (i believe it was somewhere at PMK docs, but i can't find that right now), so, if this confuses you, try to remove that for the start;
- The main feature of PMK is the [chain](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md#chaining). You definitely should write your code according to this principle;
- Also, don't forget about errors. Use `catch` at the end of the chain for that.

Final example of your code:

```
firstly {
    self.createCategoryComponents(masterComponent: masterComponent)
}
.done { createdComponents in
    completion.resolve(nil, createdComponents)
}
.catch { error in
    // don't forget about errors
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about second suggestion. Your code is not really good formatted, so i thought you have this problem.